# How to rotate 3 servo motors when 6 led lights are lit using EMG signals

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, servo, robotics

I am completely new to arduino and trying to do a school project where i will be able to more 3 fingers with the help of a servo motor using EMG signals.
Right now i am able to read the signals. I just want to modify the code in such a way that when all 6 lights are lit on my emg reading device the servo with rotate by 90 degree. And when all leds are off the servo motor will go back to its initial position, that is will rotate back by 90 degree.
I badly need help over here. Here is the code:

```
 #define NUM_LED 6  //sets the maximum numbers of LEDs
#define MAX 45     //maximum posible reading. TWEAK THIS VALUE!!
int reading[10];
int finalReading;
byte litLeds = 0;
byte multiplier = 1;
byte leds[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); //begin serial communications
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LED; i++){ //initialize LEDs as outputs
    pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    //take ten readings in ~0.02 seconds
    reading[i] = analogRead(A0) * multiplier;
    delay(2);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){   //average the ten readings
    finalReading += reading[i];
  }
  finalReading /= 10;
  for(int j = 0; j < NUM_LED; j++){  //write all LEDs low
    digitalWrite(leds[j], LOW);
  }
  Serial.print(finalReading);
  Serial.print("\t");
  finalReading = constrain(finalReading, 0, MAX);
  litLeds = map(finalReading, 0, MAX, 0, NUM_LED);
  Serial.println(litLeds);
  for(int k = 0; k < litLeds; k++){
    digitalWrite(leds[k], HIGH);
  }
  //for serial debugging, uncomment the next two lines.
  //Serial.println(finalReading);
  //delay(100);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Why not use a linear  servo with EMG feedback on pulse rate?

Answer (score 1):

Apart the problem you have (that the constants are not defined), what you are asking can be easily solved by looking at the servo library.

The servo library tells you that

1. You have to include the servo library header: `#include <Servo.h>`
2. You have to add a variable to hold the object: `Servo myservo;`
3. You have to attach the object to a pin: `myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);`
4. Finally you can move the motor to any position (0 <= x <= 180) with the syntax `myservo.write(val);`

In your code, then, you have the variable `litLeds` which tells you how many leds are there. Particularly if you have 6 (or more) leds light you will move to 90°, while with 0 (or less - even if this is meaningless) you reset to 0. So the complete code is

```
#include <Servo.h>

int finalReading;
byte litLeds = 0;
byte multiplier = 1;
byte leds[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
Servo myservo;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600); //begin serial communications
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LED; i++){ //initialize LEDs as outputs
        pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
    }
    myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
    myservo.write(0);
}

void loop(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    //take ten readings in ~0.02 seconds
        reading[i] = analogRead(A0) * multiplier;
        delay(2);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){   //average the ten readings
        finalReading += reading[i];
    }
    finalReading /= 10;
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_LED; j++){  //write all LEDs low
        digitalWrite(leds[j], LOW);
    }
    Serial.print(finalReading);
    Serial.print("\t");
    finalReading = constrain(finalReading, 0, MAX);
    litLeds = map(finalReading, 0, MAX, 0, NUM_LED);
    Serial.println(litLeds);
    for(int k = 0; k < litLeds; k++){
        digitalWrite(leds[k], HIGH);
    }
    if (litLeds >= 6)
        myservo.write(90);
    else if (litLeds <= 0)
        myservo.write(0);

    //for serial debugging, uncomment the next two lines.
    //Serial.println(finalReading);
    //delay(100);
}
```

Please note that some `define`s are missing (e.g. the `MAX`, `NUM_LED` and `SERVO_PIN`)